# What does "square something" mean?

Tags: meaning, american-english

I've come across it in the 12th episode of the 3rd season of *the Walking Dead*. Here is the context:

> Morgan: You will be torn apart by teeth or bullets.
>
> You and your boy.
>
> Your people, but not me.
>
> Because I am not gonna watch that happen again.
>
> Man, you take the guns.
>
> Rick: You know there's a chance. That's what you can't **square**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, "square" means "balance", or "settle" or "agree".

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/square

The usage is a little odd, but good synonyms in this sentence would be either "accept" or "justify".

Answer (score 1):

> 5 a : exactly adjusted : precisely constructed or aligned (MW)

To “[square](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/square)” things in construction is to align them, to make them fit together correctly.

We can apply the same meaning to *ideas*, meaning to make two ideas fit together in our minds. This is usually in the form “can’t square X with Y”, but in your example, both X and Y are presumably supplied by context. (One of them seems to be having guns, but I can’t find the other in your quote.)